# Two CSV files, match a pair from a row with matching values in 2nd CSV file, in a single column consisting of the same type of values

Tags: python, pandas, loops, csv

I have two CSV files and I'd like to match a pair (a set of two) of the same type int values from a row (loop through n rows) with matching values in the 2nd CSV file, in a single column consisting of the same type of values that are repeated.

So far, I wrote this code but it is extremely time-consuming, maybe there are pythonic short-cuts to this problem?

```
c1=0
c2=0

def append_list_as_row(file_name, list_of_elem):
    # Open file in append mode
    with open(file_name, 'a+', newline='') as write_obj:
        # Create a writer object from csv module
        csv_writer = writer(write_obj)
        # Add contents of list as last row in the csv file
        csv_writer.writerow(list_of_elem)

pairs = pd.read_csv('pairs.csv',delimiter=';')
df = pd.read_csv('02_Data_test.csv',delimiter=',')

foo = open('foo.csv', 'w')
with open('foo.csv', 'w', newline='') as outcsv:
    writer1 = csv.DictWriter(outcsv, fieldnames = ["##","lac","cid","msisdn","imei","event_type","tstamp","long","lat","max_dist","cell_type","start_angle","end_angle","msisdn1"])
    writer1.writeheader()

for i in range(0,122,1): #range(len(pairs)): 
    for j in range(0,174123,1): #range(len(df)):

        if pairs.iloc[i,0]==df.iloc[j,3]:
            c1+=1
            print(i)
            append_list_as_row('foo.csv', df.iloc[j,:])        
        if pairs.iloc[i,1]==df.iloc[j,3]:
            c2+=1
            print(i)
            print(j)
            print("")
            append_list_as_row('foo.csv', df.iloc[j,:])        

        #if pairs.iloc[i,1]==df.iloc[j,3]:
         #   c2+=1
          #  print(i)
           # print(j)
            #append_list_as_row('foo.csv', df.iloc[j,:])  

    print("------------------------")
    append_list_as_row('foo.csv', "")
```

Comment: Can you please add sample input/output to your question?

Comment: input: a pair from 1 CSV, row1 158530063945;158528861599 and matching these two numbers in one column from 2 large CSV to retrieve the corresponding/accompanying   data, say output: ##,lac,cid,msisdn,imei,event_type,tstamp,long,lat,max_dist,cell_type,start_angle,end_angle,msisdn1 (header) and row1 7471,7717,31137,158530063945,867007010117890.0,0,1369278960506,37.5842,55.6137,1349,OUTDOOR,90.0,150.0,158530063945 and row2 7395,7717,31137,158528861599,12439009133970.0,0,1369278754613,37.5842,55.6137,1349,OUTDOOR,90.0,150.0,158528861599

Comment: Okay.
So you have two CSV files, with the exact same headers.
And you're trying to access them both, simultaneously, to retrieve the data using the 'msisdn' column. Am I right?

Comment: Or, do you have 2 CSV files, with one holding these 'msisdn' pairs, and the other containing "##,lac,cid,msisdn,imei,event_type,tstamp,long,lat,max_dist,cell_type,start_angle,end_angle,msisdn1" these headers?

Comment: Headers are different, only one common header 'msisdn'. In 1st CSV there are two 'msisdn' columns containing pairs of cell phone numbers belong to N the same person and 2nd CSV contains only one 'msisdn' column with many instances of using these numbers as suggested by geolocation/towers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the pd.isin([list]) function of pandas.DataFrame to extract the data from CSV2, that belongs to the pair of `msisdn` numbers in your CSV1

Sample Input

```
pairs
msisdn1   msisdn2
msisdn1  msisdn11
msisdn2  msisdn12
msisdn3  msisdn13
msisdn4  msisdn14
msisdn5  msisdn15

data
test    moretest    no_test    msisdn
test1   moretest1   no_test1   msisdn1
test2   moretest2   no_test2   msisdn2
test3   moretest3   no_test3   msisdn3
test4   moretest4   no_test4   msisdn4
test5   moretest5   no_test5   msisdn5
test6   moretest6   no_test6   msisdn6
test7   moretest7   no_test7   msisdn7
test8   moretest8   no_test8   msisdn8
test9   moretest9   no_test9   msisdn9
test10  moretest10  no_test10  msisdn10
test11  moretest11  no_test11  msisdn11
test12  moretest12  no_test12  msisdn12
test13  moretest13  no_test13  msisdn13
test14  moretest14  no_test14  msisdn14
test15  moretest15  no_test15  msisdn15
test16  moretest16  no_test16  msisdn16
test17  moretest17  no_test17  msisdn17
test18  moretest18  no_test18  msisdn18
test19  moretest19  no_test19  msisdn19
test20  moretest20  no_test20  msisdn20
```

Code:

```
csv1 = pd.read_csv('pairs.csv')
csv1 = pd.read_csv('02_Data_test.csv')
# res is a list that will hold all the extracted rows
# and we will finally append all results into a DataFrame
res = []
for pairs in csv1.values.tolist():
    res.append(csv2[csv2['msisdn'].isin(pairs)])

df = pd.concat(res)
df.to_csv('result.csv', index=False)
```

Sample Output

```
      test    moretest    no_test    msisdn
0    test1   moretest1   no_test1   msisdn1
10  test11  moretest11  no_test11  msisdn11
1    test2   moretest2   no_test2   msisdn2
11  test12  moretest12  no_test12  msisdn12
2    test3   moretest3   no_test3   msisdn3
12  test13  moretest13  no_test13  msisdn13
3    test4   moretest4   no_test4   msisdn4
13  test14  moretest14  no_test14  msisdn14
4    test5   moretest5   no_test5   msisdn5
14  test15  moretest15  no_test15  msisdn15
```

Hope this helps.